# How to update mysql database in android using php session variable

Tags: android

hai am doing reset password.here i want to update my table with password using email stored in session.how would i make it possible?can anyone guide me.
any help will be appreciated.

Main.java

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
        EditText pass,repass;
        Button reset;
        String txtpass,retpass;
        HttpResponse response;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_resetpass);
    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    txtpass=pass.getText().toString();
                    retpass=repass.getText().toString();
                    new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);
    }
    });
    }
   class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

         private void postData(String pass,String cpass) {


             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx/update.php");

             try {
                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);


                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cpass", cpass));

                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
             }

         }

         @Override
         protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
             postData(txtpass,retpass);
             return null;
         }

          }
}
```

update.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$sel=mysql_select_db("xxx",$con);
$vmail =$_SESSION['mail'];

$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$cpass=$_POST['cpass'];


$query_update=mysql_query("UPDATE member SET pass='$pass',cpass='$cpass' WHERE email='$vmail'", $con);



//echo $rows;
 if($query_update) { 
 echo "Updated Successfully"; 

 }
 else  {
    echo "Error in updation"; 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

where you are planning to use PHP Session Variable in Java/JSP Pages? Which web server you are using?

Please let me know more details on this so that I can help you on this.

For your reference - http://www.cyberspice.org.uk/blog/2009/03/19/using-php-sessions-from-java/

Comment: sorry for late response.am using apache webserver.the problem is that my android app doesn't identifies the session variable.when i changes the where condition with field data it works.@Parag Bhavsar